# Better solution to two try statements?

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to make a GUI with one button to connect and accept incoming connections. I like to code the button's action listener like this:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        try 
        {
            socket = serversocket.accept();  //accepts incoming connections
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);   //tries to connect if
        }                                    //servsock.accept() times out
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

If serversocket.accept() times out it causes an Exception so the next line is skipped. Must I put them in two different try blocks or is there a better way to do it? I cant throw Exceptions here, but if Exceptions *were* thrown would it allow the code to continue to the next line when an Exception shows up?

I don't want to code my own exception handler, should i just use two try statements?

Comment: I'm confused -- why do you think that you need two try blocks? Note that you should avoid catching plain vanilla Exceptions and instead should catch specific Exception types. Also, you're not going to want to make those socket calls on the Swing event thread but rather in a background thread, such as that created by a SwingWorker, else you'll lock your GUI.

Comment: I'm very confused, why are you throwing away the socket you accepted to create a client socket.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: yes, come to think of it, that is very strange code. The Socket is assigned on the first line of the try block so the second isn't needed or wanted. Very strange indeed. Also the catch block should never be empty.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch good catch, pun intended.

Comment: FYI: Swing is not thread safe. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details...

Comment: The only reason you might want compound `try-catch` is if you wanted to handle the time out differently then the communications with the incoming connection...having said that, you should be processing the incoming connection in a separate thread anyway...so it's kind of mute...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: yep it's a moot point. He should be doing this in a SwingWorker and in his PropertyChangeListener, when the SwingWorker is StateValue.DONE, he should call `get()` inside of try/catch blocks and act on the exceptions there.

Answer (score 1):

You need two try blocks for what you're trying to do - however, i don't think you should be doing what you're trying to do.

The code as you pasted will not execute the second `socket = new Socket` line if an exception is thrown. If you wanted that second line to execute, you're right, you'd have to pop it into the `catch` block, and in that wrap another try/catch in case that blew up.

Like this:

```
    try 
    {
        socket = serversocket.accept();  //accepts incoming connections
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
          //catch this and deal with it. 
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that you don't need to do what you're doing - I'm not 100% familiar with sockets (i'm just reading the api [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html)) - but i think your code should read:

```
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            try {
                //create a server socket to wait on some ip and port
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(ip, port);   

                //create a socket when a connection hits the ip and port
                socket = serversocket.accept();  //accepts incoming connections

            }
            catch (IOException e){
               //deal with io exception, depends on what you're doing.

            }
            catch (SecurityException e){
               //deal with this, i don't know what it is. 
               //Probably you don't have a security manager(?), 
               // so you can leave this empty
            } 
            catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
               //no timeout, because we didn't set one in the ServerSocket constructor.
               //leave this empty
            }
            catch (IllegalBlockingModeException e){
               //wow sockets have exceptions, huh?
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
               //you no longer need this catch block. Technically you shouldn't have
//one, but given the number of exceptions this thing throws that you aren't doing 
//anything about because they're probably not relevant, you might want to just have 
// this one... your call.


            }
        }
    }
```

OF course, maybe your button is something that, when clicked, sits and waits for the socket connection, and you defined the ServerSocket somewhere else with a timeout, and you want stuff to happen if the timeout fails.

If *that* is the case, then you will want to **call the relevant function that restarts the socket** from within the catch block.

Like this:

```
    try 
    {
        socket = serversocket.accept();  //accepts incoming connections
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    //i left out the other exception handlers for clairty
        //call a function here that does recreates the serversocket on the port
        //in *that* function you will do exception handling for that call. 
        makeANewServerSocketFunctionBecauseTimedOut();
    }

    ...
    private void makeANewServerSocketFunctionBecauseTimedOut(){
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);   //tries to connect 
        } catch (Exception e) { //consider putting all the specific exceptions here
            // i don't know what you'd want to happen if this failed.
        } 
    }
```

But after reading the comments - and again, i'm really not familiar with sockets and swing at all - you might need to wrap all this in some sort of SwingWorker, which is a multi threading tool, because i think, as it is, your entire application will hang until you get a connection... or the timeout happens. As in, none of the other buttons will work.

And you probably don't want that at all.

So maybe everything i wrote is crazy! Sad.

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** need two `try` `catch` as long as the code that throws an exception is put inside the try.

Anything that happens inside this try will be caught.

```
try 
{
     socket = serversocket.accept();  //accepts incoming connections
     socket = new Socket(ip, port);   //tries to connect if
}                                    //servsock.accept() times out

catch (Exception e) 
{
    // Do something here, because an exception happened above.
}
```

Your brackets are pretty much saying: anything inside that throws an exception, catch it.

Answer (score 0):

> If serversocket.accept() times out it causes an Exception so the next line is skipped.

The entire rest of the `try` block is skipped.

> Must I put them in two different try blocks

You need to put them into different blocks anyway. You never want to execute both these lines of code one after the other. You only want to try the connect (whyever you're doing that) if the accept failed.

> I cant throw Exceptions here, but if Exceptions were thrown would it allow the code to continue to the next line when an Exception shows up?

You don't *want* to proceed to the next line in any situation whatsoever. You want to process the accepted socket if there is one, and attempt to connect if the accept failed. Ergo, different blocks.

> I don't want to code my own exception handler

Why not?

> should i just use two try statements?

You *have* to use two try statements. One to `try/catch` the `SocketTimeoutException` on `accept(),` then if you want to attempt a connection on that condition you must have a new `try`, unless you're prepared for this method to throw `IOException` to the caller.